# Tool for visualizing long time series data

Tags: visualization, tools, software-recommendation

I am searching for a software / tool / R package (any of these) that enables easy visualization of a time series.

My problem is the following:

- I have a multiple time series with 7 attributes
- I want to have all 7 attributes plotted beneath each other with a own y-axis
- I want to be able to set y-axis resolutions for the plot
- The time series is very long (1 year) but I want to look at each day individually and then basically scroll right to see the next day

Comment: Any reason why faceting of 7 ggplots does  not apply? 365 values is not that much...

Comment: oh my post did not make this clear: it 1 observation per minute, meaning 1440 * 365 values

Comment: The problem with the ggplot facets is that (as far as I know) you can not set manual different y-axis scales for each attribute. I want for example to set the y-axis for attribute_1 from 1 to 1000, for attribute_2 from 4000 to 8000. Would be happy if you prove me wrong and show that this is possible.